# CPU usage of a process in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, cpu, cpu-usage

I have a NodeJS application that spawns processes on a server with 24 cores. As a rule, I do not spawn more than one process per core (for a total of 24 processes at most). I would like to know the CPU usage of the core where each process is spawn. Is it possible to investigate something like this? I know I can use `os.cpus()`, but this returns a more general info on all the CPUs in the machine rather than the one where the process I'm querying is working on.

Is it possible to do something like this with what we have in NodeJS? I wouldn't like to rely on executing (heavy) bash scripts from NodeJS to know something like that.

Answer (score 6):

Try [node-usage](https://github.com/arunoda/node-usage) for tracking CPU using the PID

You can use node-usage like below

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var usage = require('usage');

var ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg');
usage.lookup(ffmpeg.pid, function(err, usageInfo) {

    console.log(usageInfo); // { cpu: 2.4, memory: 100065280 }
});
```

Comment: in the above code I'm spawning a new ffmpeg child_process, then we can get pid directly (as `ffmpeg.pid`)

Comment: You might want to mention that you're the author of said module.

Comment: From the library github page "Depricate Notice: This project works. But there's a much better project with a similar API.
It even does not need a binary addon (So, it's easy to use). 
See pidusage: https://github.com/soyuka/pidusage" - `npm install pidusage`

Answer (score 3):

Of course I could be wrong, but I'm not sure there is an API for worker-process CPU usage, but you can get per core for all cores: http://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_cpus

On another note: For such power, you might want to consider checking that you have access to all of the system's memory. V8 limits to a default that requires re-compiling in order to have "deeper-pockets' for memory access.

Comment: Well the one you linked is exactly what I meant by mentioning `os.cpus()` in my question. Anyways thanks for the tip about V8 and its limits. For now I just want to see which portion of each core I'm using with the workers/processes. Later I might as well improve what V8 uses of my cores.

Comment: You can get the process PID. Then you can call a command to the shell getting the details of the PID.
Get process PID: console.log('This process is pid ' + process.pid);
http://www.dzone.com/snippets/execute-unix-command-nodejs
From here, you'll need to lookup linux syntax for getting PID details.

Glad that the answer was partially helpful. Any vote up would be appreciative.